# Linux Mint will not allow traffic from one specific PC on LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, linux-mint, samba

I was editing /etc/network/interfaces, and then decided to change my settings over VNC instead. This halted my SSH session and also my VNC. I'm not sure if this locked me out or not, but I set cron up to restore an old copy of /etc/network/interfaces later that night and was able to SSH into the machine. Now I find that all connections from that machine--from both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 can't reach the Mint Machine.

Here's output from ssh -vv.

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

This isn't just SSH, because Putty can't get in, VNC can't get in, Remmina can't get in, nor can SMB on either OS on the same PC.

All other devices on the network get SMB, VNC, and SSH without issue.

I have no recourse except to reinstall--which I'd much rather NOT do. This PC is my main workstation I work on. Any thoughts welcomed.

Comment: Recheck what you have configured here 

 /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: This is my network settings with bridge, My Router IP range in 192.168.1.0 modify yours as need. If you don't have a bridge vomit the lines below dns-nameservers

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9497893/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, IR. The Linux demons were kind to me tonight. After resetting the network settings with VNC on another PC and rebooting three times and walking away for a few hours (and then doing a hard reset after the PC had locked down all network traffic) it's back to normal. Computers are weird. I have no idea what fixed it but I'm calling this solved.

Comment: Happy to hear from you.